# How to bind an AngularJS variable as a Polymer global?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, global

I have an object variable in an Angular controller with some properties. I want to create a series of polymer elements that takes that variable an the name of the property and shows them in a specific format (depending of type and other attributes). Something like the next example:

```
<polymer-element name="x-property" attributes="data property">
    <template>
        {{data.labels[property]}}: {{data[property]}}
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('x-property', {            
           data: {}
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

And then I use it as this:

```
<x-property data="{{person}}" property="firstName"></x-property>
```

That works just fine. But now I want to avoid to specify the attribute data in all the elements. Reading Polymer documentation I see that it is possible to have global variables. I followed the example created the app-globals element, as shown in the api guide but when I try to access the property, instead of having the object "person" I got the text "{{person}}"

```
<polymer-element name="app-globals" attributes="values">
    <script>
        (function () {
            var values = {};

            Polymer('app-globals', {
                ready: function () {
                    this.values = values;
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; ++i) {
                        var attr = this.attributes[i];
                        values[attr.nodeName] = attr.value;
                    }
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="x-property" attributes="property">
    <template>
        <app-globals id="globals" values="{{globals}}"></app-globals>
        {{globals.data.labels[property]}}: {{globals.data[property]}}
        {{globals.data}}
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('x-property', {
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

So in my html I have:

```
<app-globals data="{{person}}"></app-globals>
<x-property property="firstName"></x-property>
```

And the result I get is just this:

```
:
{{person}}
```

Is there anyway I can make this work as it works in the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because attributes are only strings, this code `values[attr.nodeName] = attr.value;` cannot capture your object-valued data. Instead, JavaScript converts your object to a string, which is why you see `[Object object]`.

Capturing objects with mustaches (`{{ }}`) is a special Polymer feature that you enable by *publishing* the property as an attribute (or listing it in the *publish* map in the prototype).

If, instead of making `app-globals` generic, we instead publish `values` and `data` directly, then we can make it work like so:

```
<polymer-element name="app-globals" attributes="values data">
  <script>
    (function () {
      var values = {};
      Polymer('app-globals', {
        created: function() {
          this.values = values;
        },
        dataChanged: function() {
          this.values.data = this.data;
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="x-property" attributes="property">
  <template>
    <app-globals values="{{globals}}"></app-globals>
    {{globals.data.labels[property]}}: {{globals.data[property]}}
    {{globals.data | json}}
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-property', {
      json: function(s) {
        return JSON.stringify(s);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Your original code doesn't have the `json` filter, but otherwise we are again asking Javascript to put an object in a string context, and it will render `[Object object]`.

http://jsbin.com/vusayo/10/edit

Comment: Alright... I have being playing a bit with your example. Though I have to make a little change as {{person}} in what I'm doing comes from the scope of AngularJs controller.

The only change I made is in the dataChanged event:
    dataChanged: function() {
          this.values.data = JSON.parse(this.data);
        }

http://jsbin.com/tejolekokige/2/edit

Comment: Fwiw, if you put `data: {}` in your `app-globals` prototype, that tells Polymer you expect an object, and Polymer will do the JSON.parse for you.
http://jsbin.com/tejolekokige/3/edit

Comment: Duh... I forgot that. Thanks again :)